# How to get matched location_name on runtime by lua in openresty

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

In rewrite_by_lua phase， I want to get the matched location name on runtime。

For example：
nginx server config：

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location /test {
        return 200 "test";
    }
    location /test/api {
        return 200 "test";
    }
    location ~ /id/\d* {
        return 200 "api";
    }
}
```

if I visit http://127.0.0.1/test/api/abc, I want get the nginx location name: /test/api

if I visit http://127.0.0.1/test/ddd, I want get the nginx location name: /test

if I visit http://127.0.0.1/id/123, I want get the nginx location name: /id/\d*

openresty version: 1.19.3.1

can you help me？